# Getting a 404 error when trying to post a new object to a user

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to post a new record to stores/user/userId using the userId which I have going to local storage.

It's giving me the error localhost:8080/user/5bebf6bd4a4f7b340c62572a not found.

I'm assuming my routes are not set up correctly?

I can post it to the basic '/' which sends it to the global '/stores' path but I need to have it be specific to the user?

//in main server js file

```
const storeRoutes = require('./routes/stores');
app.use('/stores', storeRoutes);
```

// in router file

```
router.post('/user/:id', (req, res) => {

  Store.create({
    userID: req.body.userID,
    name: req.body.name,
    sort: 'list'
  }).then(item => {
    res.status(201).json(item);
  });
});
```

// in local js file

```
$(document).on('click', '#availableStr', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var newStore = {
    name: this.name,
    sort: 'list',
    userID: userId,
  };


  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/user/' + userId,
    data: newStore,
    success: function(newStore) {
      alert(`${newStore.name} Added!`);
      console.log(newStore);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you have the stores route included wouldn't the full route to aim for be 'stores/user/:id'? You could put your POST method in the main file and see if it gets hit.

Comment: That was all it was, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Steve was correct, I just needed to change my local js file path